# How to check internet connection?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use ConnectivityPlugin (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected field) to check the Internet connection. The problem is that it only checks if the internet connection button is pressed. That is, if I am connected to the mobile network, but there is no Internet itself (for example, problems from the operator), then the CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected field for such a situation returns true (although there is no connection). Question: how to check whether there is access to the Internet? Thanks

Comment: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/PingaHost.html

Comment: thanks but it not working for me, IsRemoteReachable always return false.This does not work even if there is an internet connection.

Comment: @mrmaaak "Question: how to check whether there is access to the Internet?" You will need to test the access of a specific host on the public internet, you can use something like https://google.com:80 to test for a response, or an ICMP response from 8.8.8.8, etc... of course, directly testing access to a "health" page/port your API server would be better...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan, Func) method.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
        //insert checking of internet connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "google.com" is always up and running:

```
if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    try { 
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        String host = "google.com";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 1000;
        PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success){
            // Your code here...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add the following code to your App.xaml.cs class OnStart method and that take care of it.

```
  CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += (sender, e) =>
  {
      if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
      { 
         Console.WriteLine("Internet connectivity lost");
      }
  };
```